Swagger with app running inside docker container
I have and API written in go that is running inside docker container with docker compose file, here it is:
hotel-service:
   build:
     context: .
     dockerfile: ./hotelservice/Dockerfile
   volumes:
     - .:/code
   ports:
     - "8081:8081"
     - "50051:50051"
     - "5745:5745"
   networks:
     - hotel-booking-network
   depends_on:
     - postgres

I'm trying to add Swagger ui to run it on localhost:8081/swagger/index.html, that's how I do it in main.go:
mux.Handle("/swagger/*", httpSwagger.Handler(httpSwagger.URL("swagger/doc.json")))

Next to main.go located folder docs, that is generated using swag cli, I'm importing it into main.
The problem is, when I run my app without docker, on URL localhost:8081/swagger/index.html I see the swagger UI interface and everything works as expected, however in docker container with the same URL I get 404 error. In logs I see that requests come to my handler, but nothing happens. Here is my docker file:
FROM golang:alpine AS builder

WORKDIR /hotelservice
COPY ./go.mod ./go.sum ./
RUN go mod download

COPY hotelservice/ ./hotelservice/
COPY hotel-lib/ ./hotel-lib/
COPY protos/ ./protos/
COPY .env ./
RUN go build -o hotel-service ./hotelservice/cmd/main.go
CMD ["./hotel-service"]

I tried to change host in swagger.json config to name of my service in docker compose, nothing helps.

The swagger folder does not seems to be available in the running container. You need  to mount swagger folder inside the working directory or copy it there.
